# How do i get the like counts for the code given below?

Tags: flutter

This is the BrewTile which makes up a Brew and goes to a BrewList. There is a like iconButton for each brew in the list . How  can  i get any user to like the brew or unlike the brew..it doesn't have to show the name of the users that liked the Brew..it just needs to show the total number of the likes. And also the user has to be able to unlike if tapped second time.

```
class Brew {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String sugars;
  final int strength;
  final int likeCount;

  Brew({this.id, this.name, this.sugars, this.strength, 
  this.likeCount});
  }


   class BrewData {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String sugars;
  final int strength;
  final int likeCount;

  BrewData({this.id, this.name, this.sugars, this.strength, 
  this.likeCount});


factory BrewData.fromDoc(DocumentSnapshot doc) {
    return BrewData(
      id: doc.documentID,
      name: doc['name'],
      sugars: doc['sugars'],
      strength: doc['strength'],
      likeCount: doc['likeCount'],
    );
  }

}






      class BrewTile extends StatefulWidget {
          final Brew brew;


          BrewTile({ this.brew});

          @override
          _BrewTileState createState() => _BrewTileState();
        }

        class _BrewTileState extends State<BrewTile> {
         int _likeCount = 0;
          bool _isLiked = false;

         @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Column(
              children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
              child: Card(
                margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 6.0, 20.0, 0.0),
                child: ListTile(
                  leading: CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 25.0,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.brown[brew.strength],
                    backgroundImage: 
                    AssetImage('assets/coffee_icon.png'),
                  ),
                  title: Text(brew.name),
                  subtitle: Text('Takes ${brew.sugars} sugar(s)'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
                 Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          IconButton(
                            icon: _isLiked
                                ? Icon(
                                    Icons.favorite,
                                    color: Colors.blue,
                                  )
                                : Icon(Icons.favorite_border),
                            iconSize: 30.0,
                            onPressed: () {
                              if (_isLiked) {
                          _likeCount++;
                          _isLiked = false;
                          print(_likeCount);
                          DatabaseService()
                              .updateLikes(id: widget.brew.id, value: 
       1);
                        } else {
                          print(true);
                          _likeCount--;
                          _isLiked = true;
                          DatabaseService()
                              .updateLikes(id: widget.brew.id, value: 
      -1);
                          print(_likeCount);
                        }
                      });
                            },
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 
                              12.0),
                            child: Text(
                              '${_likeCount.toString()} likes',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 16.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            );
          }
        }



List<Brew> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      //print(doc.data);
      return Brew(
          id: doc.documentID ?? '',
          name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
          strength: doc.data['strength'] ?? 0,
          sugars: doc.data['sugars'] ?? '0',
          likeCount: doc.data['likeCount'] ?? 0,);
    }).toList();
  }


Future<void> updateLikesCount({String id int value}) async {
    return await brewCollection
        .document(id)
        .updateData({'likeCount': FieldValue.increment(value)});
  }

 Future<void> updateBrewData(String sugars, String name, int strength, int likeCount) async {
    return await brewCollection.document(uid).setData({
      'sugars': sugars,
      'name': name,
      'strength': strength,
      'likeCount': likeCount,
    });
  }


 Stream<BrewData> get brewData {
    return brewCollection.document(uid).snapshots().map(_brewDataFromSnapshot);
  }
```

It gives this error in the console.

```
flutter: true
flutter: -1
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(157)] Unhandled Exception: type 'MethodChannelFieldValue' is not a subtype of type 'FieldValuePlatform'
#0      FieldValue.increment 
package:cloud_firestore/src/field_value.dart:51
#1      DatabaseService.updateLikesCount 
package:myblogprofile/services/database.dart:75
#2      _BrewTileState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> 
package:myblogprofile/…/home/brew_tile.dart:77
#3      State.setState 
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1148
#4      _BrewTileState.build.<anonymous closure> 
package:myblogprofile/…/home/brew_tile.dart:65
#5      _InkResponseState._handleTap 
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:706
#6      _InkResponseState.build.<anonymous closure> 
package:flutter/…/material/ink_well.dart:789
#7      GestureRecognizer.invokeCallback 
package:flutter/…/gestures/recognizer.dart:182
#8      TapGestureRecognizer.handleTapUp 
package:flutter/…/gestures/tap.dart:486
#9      BaseTapGestur<…>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok so there are a couple of changes that need to be made I haven't had time to test this so try it out and let me know and if you have trouble ill be back on later to help.

**1st**

```
class Brew {
  final String id;
  final String name;
  final String sugars;
  final int strength;

  Brew({this.id, this.name, this.sugars, this.strength});
}
```

**2nd**

```
//database.dart
 List<Brew> _brewListFromSnapshot(QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
    return snapshot.documents.map((doc) {
      //print(doc.data);
      return Brew(
          id: doc.documentID ?? '',
          name: doc.data['name'] ?? '',
          strength: doc.data['strength'] ?? 0,
          sugars: doc.data['sugars'] ?? '0');
    }).toList();
  }

//This is different from last time very important changes
Future<void> updateLikes({String id, int value}) async {
    return await brewCollection
        .document(id)
        .updateData({'likes': FieldValue.increment(value)});
  }
```

**3rd**

```
//brew_tile.dart
onPressed: () async {
                      setState(() {
                        if (_isLiked) {
                          print(true);
                          _likeCount--;
                          _isLiked = false;
                          DatabaseService()
                              .updateLikesCount(id: widget.brew.id, value: -1);
                          print(_likeCount);
                        } else {
                          _likeCount++;
                          _isLiked = true;
                          print(_likeCount);
                          DatabaseService()
                              .updateLikesCount(id: widget.brew.id, value: 1);
                        }
                      });
                    },
```

This should work double check and let me know

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211844/discussion-on-answer-by-wcyankees424-how-do-i-get-the-like-counts-for-the-code-g).

Comment: huh thats is weird do you want me to still reorder things

Comment: I'd really appreciate if you would do that..is there something that you can do with this? https://stackoverflow.com/q/61284780/12205087 ..its kind of tricky..

Answer (score 1):

Please add below code in onPressed event of IconButton...

```
setState(() {
      if (_isLiked) {
        _likeCount = _likeCount--;
         _isLiked = false;
      } else {
        _likeCount = _likeCount++;
         _isLiked = true;
      }
    });
```

Comment: this works fine ..but the like Count has to updated in the firestore collection 'brews' which has a field 'likeCount' so that it can be fetched to the ui..any suggestion for that?

Comment: have you tried that code the way thats written that would just set  ```_likeCount``` back to 0

Comment: You can ad d that firestore related code in this code itself that I have mentioned above. Please add it below increment operation of _likeCount and decrement operation of _likeCount so it will automatically updated likeCount in firestore collection

Comment: yes the like count is initially 0..and after doing the setState method, it does like the post but the number of likes does not change as the it has to be first updated to the brewsCollection to the respective brew..

Comment: @wcyankees424 this is working now don't with the same function...